# Trouble with remote machine in Visual Studio Cross Platform Linux development

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform

Visual Studio supports Linux development by making use of a remote Linux machine to do the actual build/run.  [Details](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/).

I have two remote Linux hosts set up in the Visual Studio Connection Manager.  One is a cloud server I set up as a test, and the other is a machine I have on my desk.  Eventually I want the code to be running on the one on my desk.

In the VS Connection Manager, under the "OS" column, the cloud server is listed as "Ubuntu (x64)", and the computer on my desk is listed as "Ubuntu (Unknown)".

When I do a `uname -a` command on the computer on my desk I get

`... aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

vs

`... x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

For the cloud server.  Otherwise I am able to SSH into the desktop machine normally.

Is there a configuration file I can later to get the architecture to show up as `x86_64` instead of `aarch64`?  Or is there a way I can get Visual Studio to recognize that it has a 64 bit architecture anyway?

Comment: Related, you should avoid `uname -a` and `uname -m` as it usually breaks for cross-compiles. Instead, use `gcc -dumpmachine` or `clang -dumpmachine`. That will give you the ***target*** information (the machine the binary will run on); not the ***host*** information (the machine you are compiling on). The target is what you care about. Also see [How to distinguish armel and armhf at runtime?](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-arm@lists.debian.org/msg19914.html) on the Debian-ARM mailing list. It is roughly the same problem.

Comment: Some of the suggestions here: https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/110 might help.